# How to use ListString in groupBy ? with flutter

Tags: flutter

Hello I try to display a list of data grouped by date.

First I load all key/value saved with sharedpreference
after I use regex to match for each date the data key and data value
after I use List to add all date/data/value like that :

```
 List<String>  MylistString=[{"release_date":"2020-10-30","note3":"2222222"}, {"release_date":"2020-10-29","note3":"1111111"}, {"release_date":"2020-10-31","note3":"3333333"}, {"release_date":"2020-10-29","note4":"bdlbd"}]
```

I don't successed to use groupBy with a MyListString even after add .toString

```
var foo = groupBy({MylistString.toString()}, (i) => i["release_date"]);
```

But If I create a static String with the same data it work

Here is complet code who display a list of key value for each date, I search to group this data by date:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/flutter_timeline.dart';
import 'package:flutter_timeline/indicator_position.dart';
import 'package:intl/date_symbol_data_local.dart';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';
import 'package:shared_preferences/shared_preferences.dart';
import 'dart:convert';


void main() {
  runApp(TimelineDemoApp());
}

class TimelineDemoApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Timeline',
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: PlainTimelineDemoScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class PlainTimelineDemoScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState();
}

class _PlainTimelineDemoScreenState extends State<PlainTimelineDemoScreen> {
  List<EventData> eventsData;
  List<TimelineEventDisplay> events;

  String Data1;
  String Data2;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }


  List<String> stringList_note_formatted = [];

  List<String> stringList_date_note1 =[] ;
  String value_note1;

  List<String> stringList_date_note2 =[] ;
  String value_note2;

  load_data() async {

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    var input = '"2020-10-30","note1":"value1","2020-10-30","note2":"value2","2020-10-31","note1":"value3","2020-10-32","note2":"value4",';



    var inputItarable = input.split(',').where((s) => s.isNotEmpty);
    var i = inputItarable.iterator;
    var tmp = {};
    while (i.moveNext()) {
      var key = i.current; i.moveNext();
      var value = i.current.split(':'); (tmp[key] ??= []).add(value); } print(tmp);
    var output = tmp.keys.map((key) {
      var map = {}; map['"release_date"'] = key; tmp[key].forEach((e) => map[e[0]] = e[1]);
      return map; }).toList();
    print(output);


    if (output == null) {
      //no data available
      eventsData = [];
    } else {
      //deserialize event data from json
      var items = jsonDecode(output) as List;
      eventsData = items.map((i) => EventData.fromJson(i)).toList();
    }
    //render event data
    events = eventsData.map(plainEventDisplay).toList();
  }
  final myController2 = TextEditingController();
  final myController3 = TextEditingController();


  String note2;

  dialog_text() async{

    await showDialog<String>(
        barrierDismissible: false, // user must tap button!

        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context){
          return AlertDialog(
            shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0))),
            title:    Text(("Write something"),textAlign: TextAlign.center, style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.w600, fontSize: 20)),
            content:

            Container(
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width*1,

              child:
              new ListView(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Card(
                      color: Colors.grey[200],
                      child: Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: myController2,
                          maxLines:2,
                          decoration: InputDecoration.collapsed(hintText: "Your text"),
                        ),
                      )

                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),



            actions: <Widget>[


              FlatButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context,);
                },
                child:  Text('Validate', textAlign:TextAlign.center,style: TextStyle(
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    fontSize:15),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          );
        }
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text("Timeline test"),
      ),
      body: FutureBuilder(
        future: load_data(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return _buildTimeline();
        },
      ),

    );
  }

  TimelineEventDisplay plainEventDisplay(EventData eventData) {
    var formattedTime = DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(eventData.dateTime);

    Widget text1() {
      if (eventData.data1==null){
        return       Container();
      }else{
        return       Text("note1 : ${eventData.data1}");
      }
    }

    Widget text2() {
      if (eventData.data2==null){
        return       Container();
      }else{
        return       Text("note2 : ${eventData.data2}");
      }
    }
    return TimelineEventDisplay(

      anchor: IndicatorPosition.top,
      indicatorOffset: Offset(0, 0),
      child: TimelineEventCard(
          title: Text("${formattedTime}"),
          content: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              new Row(
                children: [
                  new Expanded(
                      child : new Card(
                        elevation: 3,
                        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                        child:  new Container(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all (10.0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              text1(),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),),
                              text2(),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                  )
                ],
              )
            ],
          )),
      indicator: TimelineDots.of(context).circleIcon,
    );
  }

  Widget _buildTimeline() {
    return TimelineTheme(
        data: TimelineThemeData(
            lineColor: Colors.blueAccent, itemGap: 5, lineGap: 0),
        child: Timeline(
          anchor: IndicatorPosition.center,
          indicatorSize: 56,
          altOffset: Offset(10, 10),
          events: events,
        ));
  }

}

class EventData {
  final DateTime dateTime;
  final String data1;
  final String data2;

  EventData(this.dateTime, this.data1, this.data2);

  EventData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json)
      : dateTime = DateTime.parse(json['release_date']),
        data1 = json['note1'],
        data2 = json['note2'];

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
    'release_date': dateTime.toIso8601String(),
    'note1': data1,
    'note2': data2,
  };
}
```

Comment: `MylistString` is not `List<String>` - it is `List<Map<String>>` - when you say `List<String>` it means that every element in the list is `String` while in your case it is `{}` which is a `Map` in dart

Comment: sorry I don't understand ^^ I'm not familiar with map/list/Json  T_T

Comment: I have just a list<String> and try to group by date to be compatible with my json model

Comment: no, you have a list of maps

Comment: I try .asMap() it seems accepted

Comment: first read this: https://dart.dev/guides/libraries/library-tour#collections - in a nutshell: if you see `[...]` it means it is a "list", if you see `{...}` it means it is a "map" (or "set" depending on content)

Comment: OK I read, I understand more the representation and context. My output structure is a JSON encode decode that I use in a model to display a list of date and data. And I used List<String> and modify the structure before add() to be compatible with JSON, but I'm loose, I have two unknow 1) how to be compatible with my model ? 2) how to group by date. I success to be compatible with my model but not with group date. And with your exemple I can group but I'm not compatible with my model. And I don't know how to correctly modify my model

Comment: ok so post dart code which creates two variables: with the data before and after modification, not any pseudocode, i mean a code which i could copy / paste and use without *any* corrections

Comment: Thank you, I have edit my post with complet code

Comment: ok input is `var input ="[2020-10-30,note1:value1,2020-10-30,note1:value2,2020-10-31,note1:value3,2020-10-31,note2:value4,]";` where is output? i only need two varaiables, not whole code, now i have `input` what should be `output` like?

Comment: I edit my code with the expected output   =>  var output='[{"release_date":"2020-10-30","note1":"value1","note2":"value2"}, {"release_date":"2020-10-31","note1":"value3"}, {"release_date":"2020-10-32","note2":"value4"}]';

Comment: `var input = "2020-10-30,note1:value1,2020-10-30,note2:value2,2020-10-31,note1:value3,2020-10-32,note2:value4,";
var inputItarable = input.split(',').where((s) => s.isNotEmpty);

var i = inputItarable.iterator;
var tmp = {};
while (i.moveNext()) {
var key = i.current;
i.moveNext();
var value = i.current.split(':');
(tmp[key] ??= []).add(value);
}
print(tmp);
var output = tmp.keys.map((key) {
var map = {};
map['release_date'] = key;
tmp[key].forEach((e) => map[e[0]] = e[1]);
return map;
}).toList();
print(output);`

Comment: Thank you I have a little change to be compatible ( add of " ") , see edit post, but I have an error with jsonDecode(outuput) =>   the argument type 'List<Map<dynamic,dynamic>>' can't be assigned to the parameter type String

Comment: what does `print(output)` show? is it what you wanted or something else?

Comment: with add of " " like above the format work if I create a static String with the result. But I can't use directly output in jsonDecode(output)

Comment: why would you even want to call `jsonDecode` if `output` is your json data? it is not string, it is a list of maps

Comment: It's ok I remove  all " " and use     json.encode(output);  it's work

Comment: what all " "? you dont have to remove anything, what exactly do you want to do with that `output`?

Comment: To be have a output compatible I had modify your example and add  " " to  release_date lite that map['"release_date"'] and add " " to all string of the input. but with add of json.encode(output) i don't need to add all this " ".